# Is $f(x)=\sqrt{9x^2 +173x+900}- \sqrt{9x^2 +77x+900}$ increasing or decreasing for $x \in \mathbb R^+$?

Tags: calculus

> What is an effective way to find that if the function, $f(x)=\sqrt{9x^2 +173x+900}- \sqrt{9x^2 +77x+900}$ is increasing or decreasing for $x \in R^+$

I was asked to find the range of $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R^+$.
I could find the limit of f(x) to be 16 at  positive infinity.
But for me to suggest that it would be its maximum and $f(0^+)$ would be its minimum, would require me to say that the function is increasing.

I was able to convert f(x) into: $\frac{96 }{\sqrt{9+ \frac{173}{x}+\frac{900}{x^2}}+\sqrt{9+\frac{77}{x}+\frac{900}{x^2}}}$.

But I'm still not able to "see" if it is increasing.

The derivative of $f(x)$ looks like a hassle, so I haven't really thought of it.

Comment: The derivative is quite easy (chain rule) and then you could calculate $f'(x)=0$ and see that there is only one solution at $-11.96$.

Comment: since square roots are in the equation i was reluctant to try to find the derivative. It would be nice if someone shows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your function form $\frac{96 }{\sqrt{9+ \frac{173}{x}+\frac{900}{x^2}}+\sqrt{9+\frac{77}{x}+\frac{900}{x^2}}}$, when $x>0$ and $x$ increases, both terms in the denominator decrease, therefore $f(x)$ increase.

Comment: ooh okay, i should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a strictly increasing function, if $b>a$ then $\sqrt{b}>\sqrt{a}$.  This implies that $\sqrt{96x+9x^2+77x+900}$ will grow faster than $\sqrt{9x^2+77x+900}$ for $x > 0$